# Node Stream: Not passing Callback Function a Value

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I am working on nodeschool.io's [learnyounode http client exercise](https://github.com/rvagg/learnyounode/blob/master/exercises/http_client/problem.md).

This is the task:

> Write a program that performs an HTTP GET request to a URL provided to
>   you as the first command-line argument. Write the String contents of
>   each "data" event from the response to a new line on the console
>   (stdout).

My solution was:

```
var http = require("http");
var url = process.argv[2];


http.get(url, function(res){
  res.setEncoding('utf8');

    res.on('data', function(data){
        console.log(data);

    })
});
```

This worked, but I am curious to why the suggested solution works.  How is console.log and console.error using the `data` or `error` objects.  They don't appear to be passed to the callback function.

```
var http = require('http')

http.get(process.argv[2], function (response) {
  response.setEncoding('utf8')
  response.on('data', console.log)
  response.on('error', console.error)
})
```

Comment: In both cases, you're passing a function that receives and prints text. In the first one, it's an anonymous function that calls `console.log`, in the second one, it *is* `console.log`. Both ways, the `data` is ending up being passed to `console.log`.

Answer (score 0):

By using `response.on('data', console.log)`, you are registering an event listener that will trigger the `console.log()` function as it's callback. The response object is an event emitter, and when your `http.get` request receives data from the remote server it emits the **'data'** event which is picked up by the listener. The event implicitly passes the received data as the first parameter to the `console.log` callback function on the listener. The same process holds true for the **'error'** event.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is can be rewritten as this:

```
function logData (data) {
    console.log(data);
}

res.on('data', logData);
```

Since your `logData` function does nothing but pass data to `console.log`, you can therefore simply pass `console.log` directly as an argument:

```
res.on('data', console.log);
```

Note that it is not the syntax of anonymous function that passes the data:

```
res.on('data', function (data) {}); // <-- `data` is not passed
                                    //     due to this syntax
```

Rather, the argument is passed because `res.on` passes data as the first argument to a function passed to it. From the documentation of the `data` event from `stream.Readable` (which is inherited by http.incomingMessage which is what `res` is above):

> Event: 'data'
>
> ```
> - chunk [Buffer|String] The chunk of data.
> ```
>
> If you attach a data event listener, then it will switch the stream into flowing mode, and > data will be passed to your handler as soon as it is available.

The `chunk` part specifies that it is the argument passed to a function passed to the `data` event handler.

---

Note that `console.log` is not necessarily implemented in a way that would allow you to do this in other javascript interpreters. In Chrome and Firefox for example the `.log()` method relies on `this` internally so it will fail if you simply pass it like that. Instead you need to bind it to `console`:

```
res.on('data', console.log.bind(console));
```

Or the more traditional way of using a wrapper function like in your solution. It just so happens that Node.js does not have this issue. But Node is not the only server side javascript implementation. So be careful when porting your code to other interpreters such as VertX.